# Arbitrary discrete distribution as a sum of dependent bernoullis

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I was wondering if any arbitrary discrete probability distribution that takes nonnegative integer values and with bounded support, can be written as a summation of dependent Bernoulli variables.

For example, the Binomial distribution can be written as a summation of independent Bernoulli variables. Can the same be said, for dependent variables, for any arbitrary distribution with these characteristics?

UPDATE: Based on comments, one way to do so is by writing the r.v. $Z=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} I(Z\leq k)$. Is there any alternative representation that kind of minimizes the interdependencies between variables? For example this makes all Bernoullis dependent on each other. But in the case of a Binomial distribution, we can surely describe it in terms of independent bernoullis

Comment: *Hint.* In the case your random variable takes non-negative integer values, note that every non-negative integer $n$ can be written as $$n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbf{1}_{\{n\geq k\}}.$$ This can be thought of as a special case of the [layer cake representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation).

Comment: Clearly you need your distribution to take non-negative integer values.  If so then yes, if you allow sufficient flexibility in the the dependency of your Bernoulli variables.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. If I understand correctly from the hint, we may write something along the lines: pmf for $X$ given by $P(X=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{Z\geq k})$, with $Z$ having the distribution we are interested in, and $X \overset{d}{=} Z$? And Bernoulli's are given by $\mathbf 1_{Z\geq k}$

Comment: It is even stronger; We have almost-sure identity $$ Z = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{Z\geq k\}} $$ for a non-negative integer-valued $Z$ by replacing $n$ by $Z$.